# replace remote repository with local repo, but keep commit history of remote

Tags: git, github

I have an Android "stored" in a Github repository. Now I did a complete rewrite of the app (started from fresh in another repository) - (how) is it possible to push the complete new repository to the existing one, but keeping it's commit history?

I guess I do not want to use the -f flag, as the commits are removed then. The best case would be to have the complete history of both repositories, but the code should only be from the new one.

Comment: When you say *complete history of both repositories* do you mean that both histories are accessible through the same github-repo? That both histories get joined into a single graph of commits? Or that you just keep the old commits somewhere for backup? Anything different?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a brute-force approach (assuming you are working on the master branch):

Go to the old, **original repo**, rm -Rf everything but the .git directory. Then:

```
git add -u
git commit -m "starting over"
```

Then, define a remote for the old repo **in your current repo**:

```
git remote add origRepo oldUrl
git fetch origRepo
```

Then, create a temporary branch **in your current repo** and push your code:

```
git checkout -b tempBranch
git reset --hard origRepo/master
git merge master
git push origRepo tempBranch
```

Then on **the original repo**:

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git merge origin/tempBranch
git push origin master
```

You could also look into using an ours/theirs merge strategy if not every single file needs to be replaced.

Comment: I would do the main branch first with the steps I provided, and after that push your other branches to the original remote and merge them in with a normal merge (so on your original repo do "git merge origin/branch1", etc). That way all of your history will be preserved

Answer (score 0):

You can commit into the same repository completely separate commit graphs. You remote repository will keep both trees as long as there are branches pointing to each. This approach may be a bit confusing for users of the repo as it is quite uncommon to have more that one commit-tree per repository, but its an entirely valid use of git.

Assuming you want `master` in your remote to point to the new repository:

```
# Rename and push your old master
cd oldRepo
git branch old-master master
git push remote old-master

# Push your new master
cd newRepo
git remote add remote url-to-remote
git push --force remote master
```

After this the `master` of your remote will point to the new commit tree, and the old tree will still be there accessible through `old-master`. If you checkout `old-master` your whole directory structure will be overwritten with the old contents, and likewise if you checkout `master`.

These two trees could also be merged into a single graph. It would look like a merge where the entire repository was rewritten, because that is exactly what it is. If you do this then both histories are retained because they are still accessible in the commit-tree:

```
# Fetch your remote in your new repo
cd newRepo
git remote add old-remote url-to-remote
git fetch old-remote master
# Assuming current branch in newRepo is master
git merge old-remote/master
git push old-remote
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be more simple:

**List your existing remotes in order to get the name of the remote you want to change.**

```
$ git remote -v

origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

**Change your remote's URL from SSH to HTTPS with the `git remote set-url` command.**

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

**Verify that the remote URL has changed.**

```
$ git remote -v
# Verify new remote URL
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git (push)
```

The next time you `git fetch, git pull, or git push` to the remote repository, you'll be asked for your GitHub username and password.

**more info at:**

https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/