# How to migrate Github Private server to another server in Azure Migration

Tags: azure, github, azure-virtual-machine

We have **Private** Github server in Ubuntu running in Azure subscription and requirement is to migrate Github to another private github server. Decided to migrate Azure from one Subscription to another subscription taking the image.

So,What are the steps/process has to be done pre and post activities for Private Github server migration from Azure to Azure subscription?

Answer (score 0):

You mean : You have a **Private Git server** not a Private GitHub server in Ubuntu I am right?

These links might to help you?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-welcomes-parse-developers/

**Changing a remote's URL**

https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

[replace remote repository with local repo, but keep commit history of remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910989/replace-remote-repository-with-local-repo-but-keep-commit-history-of-remote/37917941#37917941)

Comment: Private Github Server is hosted on Azure Ubuntu machine. Now Azure Subscription-1 to Azure Subscription-2 migration have to be done.What are the pre and post migration activities required for Private Github Server.